# Replace column headers date, into year and month, without changing remaining column headers

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe with changing column names. The column names are existing out of 'strings' and 'dates', like this:

```
print(df.columns)
Index([              'Key',    'COUNTRY',            'MARKET',
                 'A1',               'CAB',           'type',
   2021-06-01 00:00:00, 2021-07-01 00:00:00, 2021-08-01 00:00:00,
   2021-09-01 00:00:00, 2021-10-01 00:00:00, 2021-11-01 00:00:00,
   2021-12-01 00:00:00],
  dtype='object')
```

The 'date' columns are changing: it could be the case that - in the next reload - there is another column, containing a new date (format should be the same, like this: 2021-12-01 00:00:00).

**My question**: I would like to - automatically - change my column names to:

```
print(df.columns)
Index([              'Key',    'COUNTRY',            'MARKET',
                 'A1',               'CAB',           'type',
   2021_June_01, 2021_July_01, 2021_August_01,
   2021_September_01, 2021_October_01, 2021_November_01,
   2021_December_01],
  dtype='object')
```

I couldn't find a clear way of doing this. The only solution that I found, was not pretty and costed me something like 15 lines of code (change column headers into an index, using the dt function to abstract months, keep 'not date' columns as they are, combine everything together).

Hope someone has a better approach for this. Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a clean way to do this would be to check the datatype of the columns Index element and format to the desired string if it is a timestamp.

Ex:

```
import pandas as pd

# simplified example for dataframe columns
cols = [              'Key',    'COUNTRY',            'MARKET',
                 'A1',               'CAB',           'type',
   pd.Timestamp("2021-06-01 00:00:00"), pd.Timestamp("2021-07-01 00:00:00")]


cols_new = [k.strftime("%Y_%B_%d") if isinstance(k, pd.Timestamp) else k for k in cols]

print(cols_new)
# ['Key', 'COUNTRY', 'MARKET', 'A1', 'CAB', 'type', '2021_June_01', '2021_July_01']

# update in one line:
# df.columns = [k.strftime("%Y_%B_%d") if isinstance(k, pd.Timestamp) else k for k in df.columns]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the below :

```py
from datetime import datetime
new_columns = []
for col in df.columns:
   try:
      new_columns.append(datetime.strptime(col, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").strftime("%Y_%B_%d"))
   except:
      new_columns.append(col)
df.columns = new_columns
```